# How do I find use an id and return an element in that array in meteor + mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How do i find use `"_id": "WTyrTJqvf63JHQbcB"` and `"courseId": "5dWwpBp5ye492Bt4F"` and return only status?

this is not working

```
        let clas = Col_AllClasses.findOne({
            _id: classData.classId,
            "courseList.courseId": classData.courseIdList[j]
        }, {
            courseList: {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    courseId: classData.courseIdList[j]
                }
            }
        })
```

Mongodb

```
    {
      "_id": "WTyrTJqvf63JHQbcB",
      "title": "haha2",
      "school": "innervative",
      "password": "123",
      "courseList": [
        {
          "courseId": "5dWwpBp5ye492Bt4F",
          "status": 0
        },
        {
          "courseId": "sHhABCzPfkzGjdcK8",
          "status": 1
        }
      ],
      "studentIdList": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "9Pyu3QGwF6KmWAjjb",
      "title": "haha1",
      "school": "innervative",
      "password": "123",
      "courseList": [
        {
          "courseId": "sHhABCzPfkzGjdcK8",
          "status": 0
        },
        {
          "courseId": "AiEdf4FWyQkwJAnv3",
          "status": 1
        },
        {
          "courseId": "5dWwpBp5ye492Bt4F",
          "status": 0
        }
      ],
      "studentIdList": []
    }
```

Comment: Is this in an array? In that case it should be simple enough...

Comment: @Kyll yes its an array

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just fetching the document by id and then looking through the course list. Here's an example:

```js
let classId = 'WTyrTJqvf63JHQbcB';
let courseId = '5dWwpBp5ye492Bt4F';
let clas = Col_AllClasses.findOne(classId);
let { status } = _.findWhere(clas.courseList, { courseId });
console.log(status);
```

Comment: wouldnt I be returning alot of data if i have 100 courses?

Comment: Is this running on the client or the server?